# Existence of the solution of a linear parabolic pde

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, linear-pde, parabolic-pde

Good day!

Let $V = H^1(\Omega)$, $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^3$.

Consider the linear parabolic equation $y' + Ay = f$ where $f \in L^q(0,T;V')$, $y \in W = \{y \in L^p(0,T;V) \colon dy/dt \in L^q(0,T;V')$. $1/p + 1/q = 1$

$
A\colon W \to L^q(0,T;V')
$ - *linear* operator

I can't find the theorem of existence of the solution of this equation. Usually it is written about the space $W_0 = \{y \in L^2(0,T;V) \colon dy/dt \in L^2(0,T;V')$.

Could you help me, please?

Thank you.

Comment: There should also be some assumption made on $A$ to guarantee that your equation is _parabolic_. Can you include that please?

Comment: @WillieWong It is weakened coercivity property of $A$.
For example, for $L^2(0,T;V)$ space it is $(Ay,y) + \lambda\|y\|^2_H \geq \alpha\|y\|^2_V, \alpha > 0$, $H = L^2(\Omega)$

Comment: Hm, can you edit that into your question and, also in what sense are you considering the pairing $(Ay,y)$? By your definition that should be a scalar, but $\|y\|^2_H$ and $\|y\|^2_V$ are both time dependent objets.

Comment: @WillieWong This holds for any $t$.

$V \subset H = H' \subset V'$ and $(Ay,y)$ means the value of functional $A(t)y$ on the element $y$.

Comment: @jokersobak Take a look at the book by Zeidler on monotone operators. He does a nonlinear equation in this setting but yours obviously applies and will be simpler.

Comment: @student Thank you. But in this case the operator $A$ may be not monotone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that $A=-\Delta$ is one of the operators satisfying your condition.
For this operator and any fixed $1<p<\infty$, the solution of $y'+Ay=f\in L^p(0,T;V')$ is in $W=\{y\in L^p(0,T;V):dy/dt\in L^p(0,T;V')$}.
Existence of solution of this type is called theory of "maximal $L^p$ regularity", which can be found in the paper 
"Maximal $L_p$-regularity for Parabolic Equations, Fourier Multiplier Theorems and $H^\infty$-functional Calculus", written by Peer C. Kunstmann and Lutz Weis.